# C Array Merge Algorithm Produces Incorrect Result: FirstArray Merging Problem

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, sorting, merge

### Merging Two Arrays in C Without Creating a New Variable

I was working on a C programming challenge where I needed to merge two arrays without creating a new variable to store the merged arrays. Instead, I wanted to expand an already provided array and put all the values inside it.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(int array[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void mergeArray(int *firstArray, int secondArray[], int firstSize, int secondSize) {
    int firstIndex = firstSize - 1;
    int secondIndex = secondSize - 1;
    int mergeSize = firstSize + secondSize;
    int mergeIndex = mergeSize - 1;

    while (firstIndex >= 0 && secondIndex >= 0) {
        if (firstArray[firstIndex] > secondArray[secondIndex]) {
            firstArray[mergeIndex] = firstArray[firstIndex];
            firstIndex--;
        } else
        if (firstArray[firstIndex] < secondArray[secondIndex]) {
            firstArray[mergeIndex] = secondArray[secondIndex];
            secondIndex--;
        } else {
            firstIndex--;
            secondIndex--;
        }
        mergeIndex--;       
    }
}

int main() {
    int firstArray[] = { 1, 5, 7, 9, 10 };
    int secondArray[] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 12 };

    int firstSize = sizeof(firstArray) / sizeof(firstArray[0]);
    int secondSize = sizeof(secondArray) / sizeof(secondArray[0]);
    int mergeSize = firstSize + secondSize;

    printArray(firstArray, firstSize);
    printArray(secondArray, secondSize);

    mergeArray(firstArray, secondArray, firstSize, secondSize);
    printArray(firstArray, mergeSize);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The desired output is: `1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12`
The actual output I'm getting is: `1, 5, 10, 12, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12`

I've tried to debug it but couldn't identify the issue. It seems that somewhere in the code, the values in the secondArray are changing unexpectedly. Can anyone help me pinpoint the problem?
sorry if my english is bad, it's not my first language

Comment: When you "debug it", what is the *first* of these unexpected changes?

Comment: Each array has space for 5 elements. Trying to put 10 elements in `firstArray` will write past the end of the array. You need to rethink this task.

Comment: "I wanted to expand an already provided array" If you think this code expands some array, I have bad news for you.

Comment: @sdarknot This title "Merging Two Arrays in C Without Creating a New Variable" does not make sense.:)

Comment: You're writing past the bounds of your array.  That's doesn't automatically resize the array.  It creates undefined behavior which will likely result in a segmentation fault.  Both of the arrays in this example have length 5.  The valid indices for each of them are therefore 0 through 4.  If you want to resize an array, then the array can't have automatic storage, but must instead be allocated via one of the `malloc` functions.

Comment: If you want to put all values inside one array, and you do not want to alloc memory dynamically, you may assure that one of the arrays has enough capacity to hold the number of elements that need to be sorted in both arrays, in this case, you need to distinguish between the capacity of an array and the number of items to sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Instead, I wanted to expand an already provided array

That is not possible in C. Arrays have fixed size as given in the definition either explicit or implicit using an initializer. So you current code doesn't work as it writes out of bounds.

You can allocate dynamic memory using `malloc`. It can be used just like an array. Then you can use `realloc` to resize.

Besides that you merging algorithm has problems.

1. If the arrays being merged contains the same value the code just ignore the value. Even if that's intended, the code will fail because the `mergeSize` isn't correct anymore.
2. Your loop stops as soon as one of `firstIndex` and `secondIndex` becomes negative. Consequently, the code will never copy the rest of "the other" array to the destination.

Comment: i see, so from the start the ideia of making it without a third array was wrong, i dont know much about malloc or realloc yet, but i heard about, thank your for your advice, i will look onto those and rethink about the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, about the function `mergeArray` itself.

Parameters that specify sizes of arrays should have unsigned type `size_t`  instead of the signed type `int`.

As the second array is not changed within the function then it should be declared with qualifier `const`.

Also the parameters that specify sizes of arrays each should follow the corresponding declaration of the array.

That is the function declaration should look like

```
void mergeArray( int firstArray[], size_t firstSize, const int secondArray[], size_t secondSize );
```

These if statements

```
    if(firstArray[firstIndex] > secondArray[secondIndex]){
        firstArray[mergeIndex] = firstArray[firstIndex];
        firstIndex--;
    } else if(firstArray[firstIndex] < secondArray[secondIndex]) {
        firstArray[mergeIndex] = secondArray[secondIndex];
        secondIndex--;
    } else {
        firstIndex--;
        secondIndex--;
    }
```

are wrong. For example if elements of the two arrays are equal each other then neither element is stored in the current index value of `mergeIndex`.

Also the initial number of actual elements in the second array can be greater than the initial number of actual elements in the first array. In this case you need to copy remaining elements of the second array in the first array in corresponding positions.

Secondly, you can not enlarge an array after its definition. Your array `firstArray` does not have enough elements to accommodate also values of elements of the array `secondArray`.

Either you need initially to declare the array `firstArray` large enough or to use a third array that will be capable to store elements of the both arrays.

Here is a demonstraton program with updated your function `mergeArray`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printArray( const int array[], size_t size ) 
{

    while ( size-- )
    {
        printf( "%d, ", *array++ );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}

void mergeArray( int firstArray[], size_t firstSize, const int secondArray[], size_t secondSize ) {

    size_t mergeSize = firstSize + secondSize;

    while ( firstSize && secondSize )
    {
        if (secondArray[secondSize - 1] < firstArray[firstSize - 1] )
        {
            firstArray[--mergeSize] = firstArray[--firstSize];
        }
        else 
        {
            firstArray[--mergeSize] = secondArray[--secondSize];
        }
    }

    while ( secondSize )
    {
        firstArray[--mergeSize] = secondArray[--secondSize];
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    int firstArray[] = { 1, 5, 7, 9, 10 };
    int secondArray[] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 12 };
    int mergedArray[sizeof( firstArray ) / sizeof( firstArray[0] ) +
        sizeof( secondArray ) / sizeof( secondArray[0] )];

    size_t firstSize = sizeof( firstArray ) / sizeof( firstArray[0] );
    size_t secondSize = sizeof( secondArray ) / sizeof( secondArray[0] );
    size_t mergeSize = firstSize + secondSize;

    printArray( firstArray, firstSize );
    printArray( secondArray, secondSize );

    memcpy( mergedArray, firstArray, firstSize * sizeof( int ) );

    mergeArray( mergedArray, firstSize, secondArray, secondSize );

    printArray( mergedArray, mergeSize );
}
```

The program output is

```
1  5  7  9  10
2  4  6  8  12
1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  12
```

Without using a third array the code in `main` can look for example the following way

```
int main( void )
{
    enum { M = 5, N = 5 };

    int firstArray[M + N] = { 1, 5, 7, 9, 10 };
    int secondArray[N] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 12 };

    printArray( firstArray, M );
    printArray( secondArray, N );

    mergeArray( firstArray, M, secondArray, N );

    printArray( firstArray, M + N );
}
```

Comment: i tried the code you provided me, and it worked well, i see this as a way to do what is asked, there are some things i didnt know such as putchar, memcpy and that is possible to pass variable as arguments without a data type specified, i find your answer helpful and althought i cant mark more than one answer, i do want to thank for your input into this matter.

Comment: @sdarknot Actually my ansswer is the best answer. It is more informative and useful.